# Class not found when unmarshalling when installing an app via Fabric Beta

Tags: android, fabric-beta

I'm having this strange error when users are installing my app via Fabric's Beta causing the install to fail. This seems to only affect Samsung devices.

```
Class not found when unmarshalling: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics
                                     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics
                                         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404)
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264)
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)
                                         at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
                                         at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:920)
                                         at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6183)
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2695)
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2157)
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6337)
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:6115)
                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:170)
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3985)
                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
                                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics
                                         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404) 
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358) 
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264) 
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614) 
                                         at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221) 
                                         at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:920) 
                                         at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6183) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2695) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2157) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6337) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:6115) 
                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:170) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3985) 
                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453) 
                                      Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Has anyone else seen this or know what might be causing it? Thanks

Comment: did you find the solution??

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar install issue with Fabric Beta with Samsung specifically.

It occurred when we `android:extractNativeLibs="false"` - after a recent version of Android Studio started suggesting it as a lint fix.

So the workaround/fix until Fabric make fix this was to ensure `android:extractNativeLibs="true"`

Comment: But it is supposed to be false or not using it for performance, right? @scottyab?

I had a similar problem related to this flag because Fabric didn't allow to install the app in some devices. It was so so weird :-/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
I had the same problem when I built my app with only V2 (Full APK Signature) option in Studio. I have now selected V1 (Jar Signature) and V2 (Full APK Signature) and it works.
```

Got same problem, this solve my problem. From [Cannot update the app after updating SDK (app not installed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292185/cannot-update-the-app-after-updating-sdk-app-not-installed/43193441)..