# Android Studio USB Debugging not error, but when Generated APK, fail properly execute

Tags: android

Iam using Android Studio, and generated APK with build **generate signed bundle / APK**. In some Android phone it's works, but in other phone it could be cannot installed or install with can't execute properly some function.

My APK :

https://github.com/budim12/TPGAPK/blob/master/tpg-v0.3.2.2.1.apk

How i can check it / trace it / solve the problem, in phone with error function when i run this app. I test with **usb mode**, but nothing error pop up, but when i use APK, it got error function.

Add Note for broken app but success install :

- Could show login menu, could check if its empty input box or not
- But fail when get data json from API web services

Build Gradle link (remove space) :

```
https://pastebin .com/UkTSLcp5
```

Signed APK :

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: is it signed apk?

Comment: add screen shot to explain, what i mean.. cz iam new in android or java..

Comment: it's signed apk

Comment: oh, oke, thanks for the info..

Comment: put gradle file here

Comment: done, but sory for some secret words

Comment: i can't open the link please post as plain text here .

Comment: Please provide your gradle build file

Comment: Here :https://pastebin.com/UkTSLcp5

Comment: Well I guess the problem is with permissions, as you are getting data from API so are you handling runtime permissions with version of Android 6 and above?

Comment: I'm using emulator from version 4.1 until android 9.0, in emulator nothing go wrong..

Comment: And what are the versions of the devices that the app doesn't work on ?

Comment: some in version 4.2, 5, and various same kind,, T.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sory, for some apps that can't install is cz `unmarshalling` i see in debug usb mode, more spesific in mode `No debuggable processess`, so i check all output, and found that word.

Then found this link..

[Cannot update the app after updating SDK (app not installed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292185/cannot-update-the-app-after-updating-sdk-app-not-installed/43193441)

So, this is my mistake, i need to check in V1 (Jar Signature) and V2 (Full APK Signature) and it works.

But, it solve only this partial case, for other android case, which is **could install but got error function** still unsolved..

Comment: idk, but after use this, `could install but got error function` never show up anymore..

Answer (score 1):

Comment this line for future use

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

in release mode , you enabled proguard .it should be enabled in production .keep in mind, if you are in test mode it's better to disable or remove it but in production mode you should configure it .

Comment: You should told to turn off proguard only for testing. If build is succeed with proguard turned off, then re-enabled it and go on how to configuring the proguard properly.

Comment: @nyconing yup definitely right .as because he told me "cz iam new in android or java" i didn't tried to confuse him. sure you are right.